# How to modify include file in jsp page without showing blank content

Tags: java, jsp, include, logic

I am a beginner with jsp servlets, and I need some help having my page not show up blank when I make changes. I am trying to include the the code from a donate-box.jsp into the layout of the org-about-panel.jsp page, which itself is included in another view jsp file. When I makes change to donate-box, then load the view file, I am seeing a blank site, and then upon refreshing, it shows up as before without the donate-box.

Here is the code I am trying to include, from the donate-box:

```
    <logic:notEqual name="hideDonateBox" value="true">

    <form action="https://<%=request.getServerName()%><%=contextPath%>/cartDonate.do method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="targetPage" value="<%=requestedPathWithQuery%>">
    <div class="donateBox">
    <logic:notEmpty name="detailOrgBean" property="offerings">
    <table class="donateBox" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <logic:iterate name="detailOrgBean" property="relatedOfferings" id="receiver"         indexId="oppIndex" length="5">
    <tr class="donateBox">
    <td class="donateBox">
    <input type="radio" name="receiverId" 
           value="<bean:write name="receiver" property="id"/>">
    </td>
    <th class="donateBox" align="right">
```

$ -
        
        
        /donate/<%= formatter.getUrlPath((Receiver) receiver) %>">
         
   
         
         
         
         " CHECKED> 
         ">
          
          $   (Other)

This file is being included in another file with this code. I have tried commenting out the logic:notequal or logic:empty tags.

<%@ include file="/templates/donate-box.jsp" %>

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I strongly suggest reading up on [JSTL](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jstl0211/index.html) before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

This problems appears because your jsp (donate-box) can't be compiled (Such behavior I've seen in tomcat).

From quick look, I can say that requestedPathWithQuery - variable is undefined in scripting.

For more precise description you can take a look in logs